# Embedded C++ size_t size in container, question about output difference from textbook

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, embedded, embedded-linux, qemu

I'm working through the textbook *Embedded Programming with C++ Cookbook* (2020) and I'm on the section in Ch3 about using size_t to represent datatype size independent of system architecture. The issue I'm having is that the output I get is different from the output for the same program and environment as the textbook. I am doing all of this on a 2021 Macbook pro M1.

As per the textbook, I've got a docker container running linux for the build system:

```
# uname -a
Linux 271704cbe019 5.15.49-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 13 07:51:32 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

and a QEMU emulator of raspberry pi for the target system:

```
# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79+ #1 Tue Nov 26 01:41:58 CET 2019 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I am using a script from the textbook:

```
#include <iostream>
void StoreData(const char* buffer, size_t size) {
    std::cout << "Store " << size << " bytes of data" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    char data[] = "Hello, \x1b\a\x03world!";
    const char *buffer = data;
    std::cout << "Size of buffer pointer is " << sizeof(buffer) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of int is " << sizeof(int) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of size_t is " << sizeof(size_t) << std::endl;
    StoreData(data, sizeof(data));
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it on the build system for the target system arch, copy the executable over ssh to the target system, and run it. To be clear, the textbook compiles the code for the 32-bit rbpi target system, as I'm doing here. Both outputs should be the same, since they are virtually running on the same system. The textbook output is supposed to be this (so far everything I've built/ran this way has been exactly the same output):

```
Size of buffer pointer is 8
Size of int is 4
Size of size_t is 8
Store 16 bytes of data
```

But the output on my system (the target system emulator of rbpi) is different:

```
Size of buffer pointer is 4
Size of int is 4
Size of size_t is 4
Store 17 bytes of data
```

Could someone help me understand why this might be different, even though the virtual systems should be running the same as in the textbook? Isn't that a major point of using docker and QEMU?

Comment: The first is a 64-bit program, the second is a 32-bit program.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry it wasn't clear, but the program is compiled for a 32-bit arm architecture, and that is how the textbook intended it to be run.

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking. You showed two systems, one 64-bit and one 32-bit, and two runs of the program, one on 64-bit and one on 32-bit.

Comment: If I understood OP correctly, Textbook has incorrect output. Output for the 64 byte machine. Is there any errata for this Textbook?

Comment: Regarding the `Store 16 bytes of data` vs `Store 17 bytes of data` difference: this is because you've mistyped the [source code](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Embedded-Programming-with-Modern-CPP-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter03/sizet/sizet.cpp), there is no space there. By the way, C++ sources are not scripts (because C++ is not a scripting language).

Comment: Yes, thanks Maciej Polański, that makes sense to me. And thanks heap underrun, I did have an extra space so that explains the difference there. This textbook seems to have a lot of typos, most of which are insignificant, but some like this are confusing.

Comment: `size_t` is _not_ platform independent, and nothing about this code can be described as "embedded".  You'd have to worry about a book that claimed to be about "embedded" but uses a RPi running Linux as its target platform.  You can of course embed both an RPi and Linux, but you can also embed a PC and Windows - both are atypical, and neither good embedded teaching platforms ( especially further decoupled via QUEMU.